# MvvmCross Fractal Sample Throws MvxException

Tags: mvvmcross

When trying to run the MvvmCross Fractal sample, I get an Mvx.Resolve exception at:

```
private void HackSetDisplayDimensions()
{
    // Exception here
    var disp = (DisplayDimensionsService) Mvx.Resolve<IDisplayDimensionsService>();
    ...
}
```

Exception:

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to resolve type  
FractalGen.Core.Services.PlatformSpecific.IDisplayDimensionsService
```

This is latest [MvvmCross-Tutorials](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials) and MvvmCross from NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

When I switched to using the [MvvmCross-Binaries](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Binaries) libraries instead of NuGet packages I no longer see this issue.